# JavaScript - Make window scrollbar follow mouse

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, mouse, coordinates

How can I make the windows scrollbar's Y coordinate be the same as the mouse Y coordinate, how
can I make the scrollbar follow the mouse?

Comment: Does the mouse being at the bottom of the page need to mean that the scrollbar should be all of the way down? If the scrollbar's y coordinate is the same as the mouse's y coordinate, this does not necessarily happen.

Comment: Ok, but not really "same as", what I ment is that the scrollbar of the window should automaticly follow the mouse (Usiing JavaScript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a jQuery-free solution:

```
var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;

function scroll(event){
    var y = event.clientY;
    var yPercentage = y/screen.height;
    window.scrollTo(0,yPercentage*height);
}

window.onmousemove = scroll;
```

In action: http://jsfiddle.net/xF2vs/3/

On a real page, if your mouse is at the bottom of the screen, the page will be scrolled entirely to the bottom. For some reason in jsfiddle it doesn't quite make it.

What it is doing is finding how far down your mouse is on the *screen* and scrolling the document down that same percent.

Comment: Yeah but I want the scrollbars middle to follow the mouse, not the top... how?

Answer (score 1):

The most compute efficient using way of doing this utilizing DOM-L3:

```
//HTML BLOCK
<canvas onmousemove="TrackMouse(event)"></canvas>

//JS BLOCK
function TrackMouse(e){
        window.scrollBy(e.webkitMovementX, e.webkitMovementY);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my modified version Nile's reply to get a version that scrolls both X and Y.

```
var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
var width = document.documentElement.scrollWidth;

function scroll(event) {
    var y = event.clientY;
    var x = event.clientX;
    var yPercentage = y / screen.height;
    var xPercentage = x / screen.width;
    window.scrollTo(xPercentage * width, yPercentage * height);
}

window.onmousemove = scroll;
```

To scroll just the width, but not the height (as Murplyx requested a year ago) use the following:

```
var width = document.documentElement.scrollWidth;

function scroll(event) {
    var x = event.clientX;
    var xPercentage = x / screen.width;
    window.scrollTo(xPercentage * width, 0);
}

window.onmousemove = scroll;
```

Thank you Nile for the start!